# Select a node that has a specific attribute value in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database from which i want to select a specific node.
For example in my case i want to select the nodes that username is "fatma".
So how can i do that in android ? 
[image: my database structure]

package com.sifast.appsocle.user;

```
/**
 * Created by Asus on 14/06/2016.
 */
public class User {

    private String username,email,password,dateOfBirth,signUpDate;

    public User(String username, String email, String password,String dateOfBirth,String signUpDate) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.dateOfBirth=dateOfBirth;
        this.signUpDate=signUpDate;

    }
    public User(){

    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getSignUpDate() {
        return signUpDate;
    }

    public void setSignUpDate(String signUpDate) {
        this.signUpDate = signUpDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", dateOfBirth='" + dateOfBirth + '\'' +
                ", signUpDate='" + signUpDate + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

User the following code to retrieve specified data

```
DatabaseReference users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    Query query = users.orderByChild("username").equalTo("fatma");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
    }
```

Ok, if you have more than one node with child "username" = "fatma" you should use code below:

```
  DatabaseReference users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
            Query query = users.orderByChild("username").equalTo("fatma");
            List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
            query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                                     users.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
}

                        @Override
                        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

This will return a list of users :)

Comment: nope, it's single call for specific child with "username" = "fatma" :) try yourself :)

Comment: Failed to bounce to type :/

Comment: It's because you have multiple child with username fatma. Try second example. First example will also work, if you change "User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class));" to
`Iterable<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshots = dataSnapshot.getChildren(); 
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshots){
                    users.add(dataSnapshot1.getValue(User.class));
                }`

Comment: How your User.class looks like? of course if you have it :)

Comment: i added the user class in the post you can check it

Comment: @fatma19 change your variables to public :)

Comment: then try to set missing data  :)

Comment: Query query = ref.child("users").orderByChild("username").equalTo("testme"); is that true ?

Comment: nope
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
query = ref.orderByChild("username").equalTo("testme")

Comment: I am using this in my app:
DatabaseReference userReference = App.getDatabase().getReference("users");
        Query userQuery = userReference.orderByChild("userEmail").equalTo(email); 
and its working :)

Comment: and how to link that with url of the data base ?

Comment: i tried this  Firebase rootRef= new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/");Firebase    ref =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

Comment: how did u linked your app url ?

Comment: You don't need reference to child to download it. But if you want child reference (for example your -KKdk....blablabla, use dataSnapshoo=t.getKey(), then FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(dataSnapshot.getKey); :)

Comment: I am using new firebase api, I don't have to link it manually :) everything is in google-services.json